# Removing a specific index from a nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove an index from the nested list but I am getting an error. The error is "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list". How can I delete indexes in this nested loop?

```
    student = [['Alice', 90], ['Bob', 80], ['Chad', 70]]
    sname = input("Student Name?")
    for i in student:
        if i[0] == sname:
            del student[i]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `enumerate()` if you want to loop over the indexes as well as the list items. You can also unpack the `(name, score)` pairs in the same go:

```
student = [['Alice', 90], ['Bob', 80], ['Chad', 70]]
sname = input("Student Name?")
for i, (name, score) in enumerate(student):
    if name == sname:
        del student[i]
        break
```

Do remember it's generally not a good idea to modify a thing you're iterating over, and it can lead to very surprising results.

Comment: What if e.g. `'Bob'` is twice in the list?

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question. I'd use a list comprehension anyway.

Comment: @AKX Can you show an example of a list comprehension suitable for an original list with 100 million elements?

Comment: @Vlad No, I can't. I'd use a list comprehension for _this_, not 100 million items. My comment on your (pre-revision) answer wasn't to disparage it, just to note that listcomps take a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Note the indexes of the elements that need to be deleted. You can then *del* those elements but you need to do it in reverse order (for obvious reasons)

```
students = [['Alice', 90], ['Bob', 80], ['Alice', 85], ['Chad', 70]]

name = input('Enter name to delete: ')

for i in reversed([i for i, (n, _) in enumerate(students) if n == name]):
    del students[i]

print(students)
```

**Terminal:**

```
Enter name to delete: Alice
[['Bob', 80], ['Chad', 70]]
```

Comment: (Unless the list is e.g. 100 million entries long and you don't want to copy it.)

Comment: The revised answer does not necessarily work correctly, since it doesn't take into account that the list indices change when you delete items.

Comment: @AKX I think it does work because it deletes from high to low indices. Perhaps you could show an example where this would not work

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't notice the `reversed()`. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

or you can just use `filter` function:

```
student = [['Alice', 90], ['Bob', 80], ['Chad', 70]]
sname = input("Student Name?")

list(filter(lambda x: x[0]!=sname, student))

>>> out
# Student Name?Bob
# [['Alice', 90], ['Chad', 70]]
```